# Searching for Google+ Attachment

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Google plus allows for the sharing of a url; and this gets added an activity as an attachment in the activity data. Is there a way when using Activities.Seach() to target the search to the attachment url? I can share a url on g+ and if the url is part of the comment of my post then I can then pull that post when using the activities.search; however if the url is only contained in the attachment, I can't pull any activities with that url. Is there something I'm missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue with google plus, one that has been requested quite a bit from the development community. https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57

The only real option at this time it to get an aggregate count of +1s and shares as shown here: http://www.helmutgranda.com/2011/11/01/get-a-url-google-count-via-php/